# save barcode image in require directory php

Tags: php

I am working on barcode project in php. My issue is that when i click test.php, barcode image is save in same directory as my php file directory:

```
/demo1/demo2/demo3/demo4/file1/file2/file3/barcodeimage.png
/demo1/demo2/demo3/demo4/file1/file2/file3/test.php
```

but i need to save barcodeimage.png in this path:

```
/demo1/demo2/demo3/demo4/image1/image2/image3/barcodeimage.png
```

I change the directory name for your convenience

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$codeTexttwo = '1234567890.png';
$drawException = null;
try {
    $color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
    $color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

    $code_generated = new $className();

    if (function_exists('baseCustomSetup')) {
        baseCustomSetup($code_generated, $default_valuetwo);
    }

    if (function_exists('customSetup')) {
        customSetup($code_generated, $default_valuetwo);
    }

    $code_generated->setScale(max(1, min(4, $default_valuetwo['scale'])));
    $code_generated->setBackgroundColor($color_white);
    $code_generated->setForegroundColor($color_black);

    if ($default_valuetwo['texttwo'] !== '') {
        $text = convertText($default_valuetwo['texttwo']);
        $code_generated->parse($text);
    }

} catch(Exception $exception) {
    $drawException = $exception;
}
$fileNameBCtwo = $codeTexttwo.".png";

$drawing = new BCGDrawing($fileNameBCtwo, $color_white);


if($drawException) {
    $drawing->drawException($drawException);
} else {
    $drawing->setBarcode($code_generated);
    $drawing->setRotationAngle($default_valuetwo['rotation']);
    $drawing->setDPI($default_valuetwo['dpi'] === 'NULL' ? null : max(72, min(300, intval($default_valuetwo['dpi']))));
    $drawing->draw();
$drawing->finish();
}

$drawing->finish($filetypes[$default_valuetwo['filetype']]);

?>
```

Comment: And which API are you using to create this barcode ?

Comment: from this http://barcodephp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

```
$fileNameBCtwo = $codeTexttwo.".png";
```

to this:

```
$fileNameBCtwo = '/demo1/demo2/demo3/demo4/image1/image2/image3/' . $codeTexttwo.".png";
```

Check folder permission for that directory also

Comment: And if you try this: `$fileNameBCtwo = '../../../image1/image2/image3/' . $codeTexttwo.'.png';`

Comment: Actually there was permission issue. Therefore barcode images was not saving in that directory